# C++ programming - Is there a way to make gedit recognize new classes?

Tags: 12.04, programming, gedit, c++

I'm C++ programming in ubuntu 12.04 using gedit and it recognizes c++ default commands. I was wondering if I can make it able to recognize the new classes I define and change their color in the code or sth.

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there is an automatic way to do this, but you can do it manually.  If you run `gksudo gedit /usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/cpp.lang`, it will open the definition file that controls how gedit does syntax highlighting for C++.  If you want your classes to have the same color as the built-in types (e.g. bool), add a line like

```
<keyword>classname</keyword>
```

To the section that begins

```
<context id="types" style-ref="type">
```